# When using \IfEq to compare strings, is it one of those times when I should use an expandable xparse command?

Tags: conditionals, xparse, xstring

I recently asked
[How can I migrate commands and environments from LaTeX2e to LaTeX3? [XeTeX]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273820/how-can-i-migrate-commands-and-environments-from-latex2e-to-latex3-xetex)

While that question is good, the answer is likely quite complex and would take a some time to effectively answer (at the time of writing, there are no answers, however, there are a couple of helpful comments).

This question addresses one of the speed bumps I ran into on the road to LaTeX3.

Using `xparse` LaTeX3 syntax, I am defining:

1. a command holding a value (functions as variable)
2. a user command to reset that value
3. a conditional statement using xparse's `\IfEq`

Syntax for `\IfEq`:

> `\IfEq{〈stringA〉}{〈stringB〉}{〈true〉}{〈false〉}`

From the `xparse` manual:

> There are very rare occasion when it may be useful to create functions using a fully expandable argument grabber. To support this, xparse can create expandable functions as well as the usual robust ones. This imposes a number of restrictions on the nature of the arguments accepted by a function, and the code it implements. This facility should only be used when absolutely necessary; if you do not understand when this might be, do not use these functions!

*Note there is a typo in version "Released 2014/11/25": *occasions**

## Updated Code

From my understanding, \jkoclass needs to be expanded, but will not be expanded with `\NewDocumentCommand`. Should I be using `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`?

I realized that my example code was not written the way it should have been when I initially opened the question. Here is the code that I indented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\jkoclass}{}{I}
\NewDocumentCommand{\jkosetclass}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\jkoclass}{}{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\jkoimagepath}{}{
    \IfEq{\jkoclass}{I}
        {Value is I}
        {Value is NOT I}
    }
\begin{document}
\jkoimagepath{} (should result in: Value is I)

\jkosetclass{II}
\jkoimagepath{} (should result in: Value is NOT I)
\end{document}
```

### [image]

## Original Question Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\NewDocumentCommand{\jkoclass}{ m }{I}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setjkoclass}{ m }{\RenewDocumentCommand{\jkoclass}{m}{#1}} 
\IfEq{\jkoclass}{I} %<-- \jkoclass is protected automatically by the xparse definition and will therefore not be expand as desired.
  {Class is I}
  {Class is II}
\begin{document}
\setjkoclass{II}
\jkoclass{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you should use `xparse` for user level macros, and then `expl3` for internal macros.

Comment: @yo' And I quote regarding `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand
` "This command is used to create a document-level functions" `xparse` Released 2014/11/25 p.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach; you can certainly have a user level command `\jkoclass` that prints something, but if what it prints is variable data, this data should be allocated its own variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% allocate a (global) variable
\tl_new:N \g_macmadness_jko_class_tl

% initialize the value
\tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_jko_class_tl { I }

% define a user level command for printing the value
\NewDocumentCommand{\jkoclass}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \g_macmadness_jko_class_tl
 }

% define a user level command for changing the value
\NewDocumentCommand{\setjkoclass}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_jko_class_tl { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Suppose now you want to define a new user level command for printing something that depends on the variable to contain `I` or not.

Add, in the programming environment,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\jkoclassifI}{}
 {
  \tl_if_eq:VnTF \g_macmadness_jko_class_tl { I }
   { Class~is~I }     % true branch
   { Class~is~not~I } % false branch
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { V }
```

The last instruction is for making available in the programming environment a variant of the token list equality check function that takes as its first argument a token list variable.

Spaces in output in the programming environment must be specified by `~`, because ordinary spaces are ignored.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip.  The original code I posted was flawed, and I have since fixed it. Is it still the wrong approach? After thinking about it, I realized that my question could have been generalized as: Does a command stay "unprotected"/"expandable" once it is made "unprotected"/"expandable"?  I was hoping to address confusing regarding `DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: It is also very important that the command I use that actually contains the text (or in my actually case, a path for includegraphics) stays the same throughout all documents. This is because the class names could change in the future (a theoretical assumption to make code live longer :-)

Comment: @macmadness86 Sorry, I can only repeat that you're using the wrong approach. You should *never* use a user level command as a container. What's wrong with my macros, that I believe are doing exactly what you ask in the edit of the question?

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, there is nothing wrong with your macros. They work great and you explained them well with comments. I was just trying to understand the concept of protected and unprotected as it applies to `xparse` and `DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`. Your answer implies that the answer to my question is between "no" and "unclear" *(because I took the wrong approach altogether)*. "...is it one of those times when I should use an expandable xparse command?"

Comment: I feel like I am often learning how to do things from your answers, which is great. What I am not getting is a didactic answer that provides reasoning for your choices. Why is my approach wrong exactly i.e. What is wrong with using `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` or in general using user commands as "containers"? A polite critique, of course.

Comment: @macmadness86 One of the main points of `expl3` is in the separation between “performing actions” and “storing data” (functions and variables, in common terminology). User level commands should always be functions, maybe for retrieving data from variables. If you notice, `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` is described with “There are *very rare* occasion when it may be useful to create functions using a fully-expandable argument grabber.”