# How can I use a LaTeX3 variable as a path in includegraphics (solving the expansion problem)?

Tags: graphics, latex3, xparse

This problem is driving me nuts. I'd like to change the includegraphics path depending on some conditions. It seems simple, right?

I already read the answers to this question: [Passing image path to \includegraphics using a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120969/passing-image-path-to-includegraphics-using-a-macro), but I was unable to solve my issue. I learned that for `\includegraphics` the following must be true:

- The path must be expandable (requires `\edef` or cannot be protected therefore no xparse unless `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` is relevant?) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120972/13552
- includegraphics only supports one level of expansion. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120975/13552

Thanks David Carlisle -> Incorrect Statement: From my understanding, my code only requires one level of expansion, but is still not working.

Is this a rare time when I need to use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` for `\qikpicpath`?

## Code

A prerequisite is having a jpg file on directory above the tex file called test_pic.jpg. I commended out the problematic code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\qikrootdirectory}{../}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275552/13552
\tl_new:N \g_qik_pic_class_tl % allocate a (global) variable
\tl_gset:Nn \g_qik_class_tl { I } % initialize the value
\NewDocumentCommand{\qikpicclass}{} % define a user level command for printing the value
    {
    \tl_use:N \g_qik_class_tl
    }
\NewDocumentCommand{\qiksetpicclass}{m} % define a user level command for changing the value
    {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_qik_class_tl { #1 }
    }
\NewDocumentCommand{\qikpicpath}{}
    {
    \tl_if_eq:VnTF \g_qik_class_tl { I }
        { \qikrootdirectory~test_pic.jpg } % true
        { \qikrootdirectory~test_pic.jpg } % false
    }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\qikpicpath % Visually inspect expanded text.

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\qikrootdirectory test_pic.jpg}% Works

%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\qikpicpath}% Expansion Problem

\tikz \node (pic) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../test_pic.jpg}};% Works

%\tikz \node (pic) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\qikpicpath}};% Expansion Problem Related to Above

\end{document}
```

Comment: No `~` space before `test_pic`!

Comment: @egreg I am removed both `~` spaces, but my output after uncommenting the first commented out line is `! You can't use \`the letter I' after \the. <argument>`

Comment: @egreg I should also note that I use a space in that location in LaTeX2e code.

Comment: it isn't clear what problem you are trying to solve, it is usually best not to have a path anyway but here since the file extension is not hidden in the macro the comments about expansion in the referenced question do not apply at all. `\def\qikrootdirectory{../}` should work if `../` works (security settings in `texmf.cnf` might prevent reading files in a path starting `../`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Haha I suspected that my understanding was completely off. You just confirmed it. So the expansion takes this course: `\includegraphics>\qikpicpath>\tl_if_eq:VnTF \g_qik_class_tl { I }>\jkorootdirectory`? Is that right? How  is it not clear what problem I am trying to solve? The path is most definitely required in my case. The entire SVN system depends on paths.

Comment: @macmadness86 obviously the image needs to be at some path but you don't normally have to specify the path in your document. You don't specify the full path to `article.cls` in every document for example. If TeX can find article.cls it can find your jpg files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My understanding was that LaTeX could only find files within the scope of the local tex file and the installed folders `/usr/bin/texlive`. If multiple documents in separate dirs under a common directory structure must access the same picture, it makes sense to have them located higher in the tree and shared amongst docs (save resources). Multiple users can check out a fully working dir tree from the revision control system without admin rights and everything should compile. How else would I tell LaTeX where the global objects are (objs. because there are other global things).

Comment: if you can input it at all you can add that directory to your TEXINPUTS variable (or use `\graphicspath`) and then `\includegraphics{test_pic}` will work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the tip. I knew about that. However, editing TEXINPUTS would make it work on my computer while breaking paths on other machines using fresh revision copies (svn checkout). Also, there is a document that is so large that the actual root directory is reset such that each chapter can be compiled locally as individual documents. The server takes each chapter and comments out the appropriate lines, merges the chapters, and changes the root directory. It generally works quite well, providing excellent revision control. I just run into annoying snags with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @macmadness86 I'd use TEXINPUTS personally but if you want to use tex macros to configure it I can't see why `\graphicspath` doesn't do what you need why do you have to hide the filename in a macro as you comment there is no problem using a macro top hold the _path_.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well TEXINPUTS is off the table for the aforementioned reason. We keep the tex install on all machines as vanilla as possible for maintenance reasons (ease, predictability, upgradability). As for `\graphicspath`, that could be an option if `\graphicspath{\qikrootdirectory}` would work. There is a caveat to this method, however. It will introduce a constraint on the filenames. No local image may have the same name as a global image. I do not know why anybody would intentionally do such a thing, but it would be a restriction that I currently do not have.

Comment: `\graphicspath{{\qikrootdirectory}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *could* be a case where `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` turns out to be useful, but it's simpler to use a different approach.

Let's say you have the same images in color and b/w versions, in two different folders, say `./colorimages` and `./bwimages`. Your purpose is to load pictures from one folder or another in case you compile your PDF for viewing or printing.

Let's also say that the images have consistent names like `color-image1.jpg` and `bw-image1.jpg`, so you want to do

```
\mmincludegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{image1}
```

and this will load the right image, either color or b/w, just with one switch to be set in the preamble.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mmincludegraphics}{O{}m}
 {
  \includegraphics[#1]{
    \g_macmadness_folder_tl/ % the folder
    \g_macmadness_prefix_tl % the prefix
    #2
  }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setimagefolder}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {color}
     {
      \tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_folder_tl { ./colorimages }
      \tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_prefix_tl { color- }
     }
    {bw}
     {
      \tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_folder_tl { ./bwimages }
      \tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_prefix_tl { bw- }
     }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \g_macmadness_folder_tl
\tl_new:N \g_macmadness_prefix_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now you can state in the preamble

```
\setimagefolder{color}
```

or

```
\setimagefolder{bw}
```

and call, in the document, `\mmincludegraphics` as stated before.

Comment: Hm interesting approach. My situation is possibly easier in that all shared images are in a common location. I will need to consider whether introducing a new `\mmincludegraphics` command just for one graphic is a wise option. Another less clean (duplicate code) approach I've considered is putting the  `\includegraphics` command within conditional logic and hardcoding the image filenames in each condition. One complication: I would have to be able to access the optional parameters `[width=,height=]` of `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand: all the work is for a *single* image?

Comment: No, I mistakenly wrote "one graphic". I meant one graphic case. e.g. `img-label-with-cert.jpg` and `img-label.jpg` are in a common folder above the tex file's dir, but their names could be anything (but likely similar).   On the contrary, all the work is for potentially many images. As this project is for a very expensive product, I try to only use scalable options.

Comment: @macmadness86 It doesn't work like this: please, present your *real* problem with all specifications. The previous question had no image; this one has one image; the comment tells that there is one, but it can be many. I can't follow you.

Comment: Hang on. Your example is very much on track! The only difference is that I might have to switch between 3 images instead of 2. The *real* problem was in the question all along: *How can I use a LaTeX3 variable as a path in includegraphics (solving the expansion problem)?* I have a path expansion problem. Doesn't that cover it? None of the answers regarding  `\includegraphics` seem to hit the nail on the head. I've had a long day at work and I am prob. not thinking clearly anymore. I'll be back… Thx for your help.

Comment: @macmadness86 Two or three, with `\str_case:nn` is immaterial. For the expansion problem, the main fact is that `\tl_if_eq:nn` is not expandable. But a redefinition of `\includegraphics` is needed anyway.

Comment: Good to know about `\tl_if_eq:nn`. Could you confirm that the reason your code works is because `\includegraphics` sees `\g_ith_folder_tl/` and `\g_ith_suffix_tl` and expands them one time and the result is the path that needs no further expansion? The reason I am confused is that I replaced `./colorimages` in `\tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_folder_tl { ./colorimages }` with `\qikrootdirectory` and it worked! This baffles me, because doesn't that mean that `\g_ith_folder_tl/` must be expanded multiple times? If `\includegraphics` can only handle one expansion, then why does this work here?

Comment: @macmadness86 If I use `\str_if_eq:VnTF` instead of `\tl_if_eq:VnTF` (no variant generation is necessary and \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` for `\qikpicpath`, it works. When `\includegraphics` processes the file name, it performs full expansion.

Answer (score 2):

If you add

```
{\tracingmacros1
\setbox0\hbox{\qikpicpath}
}
```

Then TeX traces the expansion steps of this macro:

```
\qikpicpath ->\tl_if_eq:VnTF \g_qik_class_tl {I}{\qikrootdirectory test_pic.jpg
}{\qikrootdirectory test_pic.jpg}

\tl_if_eq:VnTF ->\exp_args:NV \tl_if_eq:nnTF 

\exp_args:NV #1#2->\exp_after:wN #1\exp_after:wN {\exp:w \__exp_eval_register:N
 #2}
#1<-\tl_if_eq:nnTF 
#2<-\g_qik_class_tl 

\__exp_eval_register:N #1->\exp_after:wN \if_meaning:w \exp_not:N #1#1\if_meani
ng:w \scan_stop: #1\__exp_eval_error_msg:w \fi: \else: \exp_after:wN \use_i_ii:
nnn \fi: \exp_after:wN \exp_end: \tex_the:D #1
#1<-\g_qik_class_tl 

\use_i_ii:nnn #1#2#3->#1#2
#1<-\exp_after:wN 
#2<-\exp_end: 
#3<-\tex_the:D 

\g_qik_class_tl ->I

\tl_if_eq:nnTF #1#2->\group_begin: \tl_set:Nn \l__tl_internal_a_tl {#1}\tl_set:
Nn \l__tl_internal_b_tl {#2}\if_meaning:w \l__tl_internal_a_tl \l__tl_internal_
b_tl \group_end: \prg_return_true: \else: \group_end: \prg_return_false: \fi: \
exp_end: 
#1<-I
#2<-I

\tl_set:Nn #1#2->\cs_set_nopar:Npx #1{\exp_not:n {#2}}
#1<-\l__tl_internal_a_tl 
#2<-I

\tl_set:Nn #1#2->\cs_set_nopar:Npx #1{\exp_not:n {#2}}
#1<-\l__tl_internal_b_tl 
#2<-I

\prg_return_true: ->\exp_after:wN \use_i:nn \exp:w 

\use_i:nn #1#2->#1
#1<-\qikrootdirectory test_pic.jpg
#2<-\qikrootdirectory test_pic.jpg

\qikrootdirectory ->../
```

Counting `->` shows that it takes twelve expansions to get `../` in this case.

It would still work with includegraphics if you use the `type` and `read` keys to tell it that it is a jpg file, but usually this is the wrong approach.

Comment: Amatuer question: Where do I put `\tracingmacros1`? Should the output be on the pdf or in the log? Also, I copied your post into a file called file and ran `grep -E '\->' file | wc -l` to make sure my eyes weren't going blind and the result was 12, not 5. I suppose the likely explanation is that I do not understand what you have posted.

Comment: sorry 5/12 was just silliness on my part, it seems I can't count:-) If you add the three lines I show anywhere in the document then the log file should have the trace I show, `\tracingmacros` is an integer register so it's just a normal tex assignment, so you can put it anywhere but if you don't limit the scope with `{..}` then you get a lot of trace output in the log as you trace ever command.

Comment: No problem. I suppose 12 expansions is too much for `\includegraphics`, hm? :-) Thank you for the comment about the internal registers-normal tex assignment.

Comment: @macmadness86 you can have 10000 expansions in the path part but if you want it to see the `.jpg` and so automatically detect the image type and use the right back end code you have to not hide that. If you do hide it you need to use type= and the other little used attributes on \includegraphics to give the information in other ways. But I can't see why you'd need to hide the file name.