# How can I implement xstring's \IfBeginWith equivalently in a non-user-level macro?

Tags: macros, conditionals, xstring

I have a string check macro `\IfBeginsWith` from `xstring` that is wrapped in a non-user level macro. I have learned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275552/13552) that the wrong approach would be to use user-level commands in a wrapper that no user sees. I should use either low-level TeX stuff (which is beneficial for the sake of understanding the fundamentals) or LaTeX 3 syntax.

I would like to check whether or not the filename starts with UserManual, DVD, or Interface. If it does, then I should do something (e.g. redefine a macro to true), otherwise I should do something else (e.g. redefine a macro to false, although it is probably the default setting anyway).

Just doing it using the semi user-level way:

Since `\jobname` exports `catcode 12` tokens (which makes sense since it must expand to any supported filesystem characters that are not escaped) and not `catcode 11` tokens, it is just easy to convert both sides of the equation with `catcode 12` with `\detokenize` (converts spaces to catcode 10 and characters to 12).

```
\IfBeginWith{\detokenize\expandafter{\jobname}}{\detokenize\expandafter{DVD}}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\def\whatever{false}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setwhatever}{m}{\def\whatever{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \g_jobname_tl
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_jobname_tl {\jobname}
  \IfBeginWith{\g_jobname_tl}{UserManual} %something like \str_case_beginswith:nn
    {\setwhatever{true}}
    {\setwhatever{false}}
  \IfBeginWith{\g_jobname_tl}{DVD} %something like \str_case_beginswith:nn
    {\setwhatever{true}}
    {\setwhatever{false}}
  \IfBeginWith{\g_jobname_tl}{Interface} %something like \str_case_beginswith:nn
    {\setwhatever{true}}
    {\setwhatever{false}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\whatever{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no “if token list begins with” predefined function. You can build it easily with `l3regex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\whatever}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \g_macmadness_whatever_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \g_macmadness_whatever_tl

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nV }
\regex_match:nVTF { \A (UserManual|DVD|Interface) } \c_sys_jobname_str
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_whatever_tl {true}
 }
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_whatever_tl {false}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\whatever{}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\jobname` is already available as the string `\c_sys_jobname_str`, so you don't need to allocate a variable for it.

The token `\A` anchors the search string at the start; the search is for one among `UserManual`, `DVD` or `Interface` and the token list is set accordingly to whether the match was found.

Comment: It would seem `\regex_match:nnTF` is a more recent addition to LaTeX 3 than the version I have because I am getting `LaTeX has been asked to use a command \regex_match:nnTF, but this has not been defined yet.`

Comment: @macmadness86 You need to update